# Changing the value of a a cell if another cell is equal to a certain value using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

So I have a sheet that looks something like this:

```
E        F     G       H
BS     m1     blah    INDC
BSB    m2     blah    INDC
BS     m1     blah    INDC
BS     m2     blah    INDC
```

What I need to do is change the value of `Column H` from `"INDC"` to `"IOE"` if the value in `Column E` is equal to `"BS"` and the value in `Column F` is equal to `"m1"` (Like the 3rd row).

I have tried to write the code several but cannot get it to work.

Comment: If you '*have tries to write the code several different times*' then you have code you can show. Show it.

Comment: Sorry about the grammar, there's a reason I'm not an English major haha. But I deleted it because I knew it was wrong. I tried to do a union with it but that lead no where. Then I tried to write if statements using AND but I guess the syntax was wrong. I though about doing the CASE statements but I don't know how i would write nested ifs inside of them

Comment: ... and yet you still have not shown any code.

Comment: let me take a second and try to rewrite something and i'll post it on here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try something like this....

```
Sub ReplaceValues()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lr As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set ws = ActiveSheet
lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
ws.AutoFilterMode = False
With ws.Rows(1)
    .AutoFilter field:=8, Criteria1:="INDC"
    .AutoFilter field:=5, Criteria1:="BS"
    .AutoFilter field:=6, Criteria1:="m1"
    If ws.Range("E1").CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count > 1 Then
        ws.Range("H2:H" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = "IOE"
    End If
    .AutoFilter
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

This code will efficiently do the job.

If you want to change the Column H value only if it is already equal to "INDC", then you need to add another criterion to the if-statement as `AND wsh.Cells(i,8) = "INDC"`

```
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim wsh as Worksheet

 Sub substitute()

 Set wsh = ActiveSheet
 i = 1

 While wsh.Cells(i,5) <> ""

 If wsh.Cells(i,5) = "BS" AND wsh.Cells(i,6) = "m1" Then wsh.Cells(i,8) = "IOE"

 i = i + 1
 Wend

 End Sub
```